# Rails redirection to index instead of show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I'm in my static page controller and I need to redirect to user index but it redirect me to user show, how can I fix it ?
I tried `redirect_to user_url, action: 'index'`
But it doesn't work, any idea ?

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: Update the question with output of 'rake routes' in your terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:
`redirect_to users_path`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
redirect_to users_url
```

Answer (score 0):

If your controller name is **users_controller.rb**

```
## Redirect to Index Page.
redirect_to users_path

## Redirect to Show page, but this will require user_id
redirect_to user_path
```